# Rider asks to install .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack even though it is installed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jetbrains-ide, rider

Why does Rider ask me to install .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack even though it is installed?

I am working with `Unity3d` using Rider.

Here is what Rider asks me to do:

> 7:41 PM    .NET Framework Not Installed: Download and install .NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack

I did download and install the pack from over [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks).

I even reopened the Rider, but the problem persists.

Anything else I could try out?

Comment: Have you rebooted since installing 4.7.2?

Comment: @mariocatch, no I did not. I will try to reboot right now.

Comment: @mariocatch, tried and it did not help. And when I try to install the pack once more it is telling me that the pack is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution over [here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207288089-Using-Project-Rider-under-Windows-without-Visual-Studio-prerequisites).

There are two approaches. The first approach should be taken if you have installed the Visual Studio and the second if you did not do that.

I have a new laptop which had no Visual Studio in it. So, I decided to try out the second approach and just follow the directions provided in the article. It did not work out even though I did exactly as said in the manual, so there is no need to try out the first approach.

But the mere Visual Studio installation tackled the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is very confusing about the current crop of .NET releases.  You probably installed the runtime, and not the SDK.

For the SDK, you need to here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks
and download the "Developer Pack".